# RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument when trying to use avahi-autoipd on Petalinux device

Tags: linux, networking, ip, iptables

I have an embedded device running PetaLinux that I wish to configure to use avahi-autoipd to use LLA on an interface.

I have been trying to do this from the CLI to ensure it works as expected, and I am consistently getting the following error output or similar (note the `client: RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument` line):

```
root@<device>:~# avahi-autoipd --debug eth0
Found user 'avahi-autoipd' (UID 997) and group 'avahi-autoipd' (GID 997).
Successfully called chroot().
Successfully dropped root privileges.
State transition START-0 -> START-0
Starting with address 169.254.15.181
State transition START-0 -> WAITING_PROBE-0
sleeping 774ms
State transition WAITING_PROBE-0 -> PROBING-0
...
State transition PROBING-1 -> WAITING_ANNOUNCE-0
...
State transition WAITING_ANNOUNCE-0 -> ANNOUNCING-0
Callout BIND, address 169.254.15.181 on interface eth0
...
client: RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
sleeping 1970ms
Script execution failed with return value 2
State iteration ANNOUNCING-1
...
Successfully claimed IP address 169.254.15.181
State transition ANNOUNCING-1 -> RUNNING-0
sleeping -1ms
```

I have examined the script (`/etc/avahi/avahi-autoipd.action`) which is failing to run/encountering the RT_NETLINK error, and it seems to be from the following lines:

```
ip addr flush dev "$2" label "$2:avahi"
ip addr add "$3"/16 brd 169.254.255.255 label "$2:avahi" scope link dev "$2"
```

Which in my specific case are the following (copied from a previous run, thus the different IP addr):

```
ip addr flush dev eth0 label eth0:avahi
ip addr add 169.254.100.200/16 brd 169.254.255.255 label eth0:avahi scope link dev eth0
```

I am somewhat stuck here though as far as continuing to troubleshoot, as networking is one of my weakest points. From what I gather, this is an issue with how the network is already configured, but I am unsure of how I would go about fixing this. I have already cleared my `/etc/network/interfaces` file as that had configured eth0 as static with an IP/netmask, and stopped another program which makes changes from running, but this embedded system has a lot of hands on it so I would expect there are network config stops happening elsewhere during startup and running of other applications.

My question is: How would I fix this error and/or go about finding what config is causing the issue and where that config is happening?

Happy to edit with more information if needed.